# How to reuse Renv from other git project

Tags: r, conda, renv

I'm working through `Renv` and how it works. I was wondering how the workflow is when I start a new project and install a project from gitlab which itself contains an renv configuration.

Is there a way to copy this renv for my new project without manually downloading it? If so, how to deal with multiple packages having a renv. Is there any functionality that checks for package version mismatches? I mean, I start a new project let's call it A, which depends on B and C. Both B and C have a renv configured which I would like to merge. I guess I have to do this manually - am I right?

Would conda be the better choice?

Comment: Here's what I would do. After installing from GitLab, execute `renv::init()`. Then choose option 2: Discard the lockfile and re-initialize the project. I also tried `renv::restore()`, but `renv::init()` ended up being the better option.

Answer (score 0):

see [the vignette on collaboration](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/collaborating.html) for your first two questions - i.e. if you have a project with renv already, use `renv::restore()`, if it does not have renv yet, use `renv::init()`. For using the same renv in a second project, I would initialise the second project with `renv::init()` but then replace the lockfile with the file from the first project, and run `renv::restore` to install the packages from the pasted lockfile.
I am not aware of a tool that does dependency resolution (i.e. your question about packages A, B, C) in R, but would be delighted if someone could point me towards one (here's where I still prefer python, with e.g. pipenv)